# Inherited prototype function is not a function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs, prototypal-inheritance

I'm trying to wrap my head around prototypal inheritance and I haven't been able to work out why my code is failing. I'm stuggling to call a function on an object where that function is inherited from the Objects prototype. My code is below...

```
const OBJ_PROTO = {
    myFunction(param = 'a') {
        if (['a', 'b'].includes(param)) {
             this.someVar = param;
        };
        return this.someVar;
    }
}

const obj = ({
    someVar = 'a'
} = {}) => Object.assign(Object.create(OBJ_PROTO), { someVar })

export default obj;
```

Then in my test I'm doing...

```
import obj from './someFile'

test('testing my function', () => {
   const myObj = obj();

   expect(myObj.myFunction()).toBe('a')
});
```

The test seems to fail and error's saying myFunction is not a function. Running Object.getPrototypeOf(myObj) correctly lists the function which leads me to believe i'm making a stupid mistake somewhere. To which im happy to be roasted on SO for. I get that testing simple code like this with Jest is very overkill but it was just another thing i wanted to familiarise myself with. Any help is greatly appreciated! If any more info is required, ask!

```js
const OBJ_PROTO = {
    myFunction(param = 'a') {
        if (['a', 'b'].includes(param)) {
             this.someVar = param;
        };
        return this.someVar;
    }
}

const obj = ({
    someVar = 'a'
} = {}) => Object.assign(Object.create(OBJ_PROTO), { someVar })

const myObj = obj();

console.log(myObj.myFunction())
```

Comment: I've [created a snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992) in the question using your code. It does return `a`.

Comment: Thanks for that @adiga, I'll make sure to add a snippet in future questions! Curious, perhaps my problem is with Jest instead?